# Use result from pgfmath with xifthen

Tags: expansion, pgfmath, pgf-core, xifthen

I try to use the results of `pgfmath` calculations with `cnttest` from `xifthen`, but it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,xifthen}

\begin{document}
  \pgfmathparse{42+77}%
  \def\val{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
  \ifthenelse{\cnttest{\val}{>=}{50}}{%
    Large
  }{%
    Small
  }%
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` (TexLive 2012) produces in the log:

```
./test.tex:7: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.7   \ifthenelse{\cnttest{\val}{>=}{50}}
                                         {%
```

And in the document (yes, the message leaves the page):

[image]

I suspect it's an expansion problem -- something I seem to be unable to wrap my head around. I know that using `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` directly (instead of `val` does not help. Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: You can simply use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\val{42+77}%` to directly save the integer part of the operation result into your `\val` macro. Then everything works as expected.

Comment: @Jake Sweet, thanks. Can you make that an answer?

Comment: Is really `\pgfmathparse` necessary? If you're dealing with integers, `\numexpr` is way handier.

Comment: @egreg I'm not too familar with the capabilities of either one, but keep in mind that I provided an MWE. Real use cases may not be restricted to integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using PGF so why not use also the conditionals of PGF ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
  \pgfmathparse{42+77<50? "Small" : "Large"}\pgfmathresult%
\end{document}
```